# material virtual-repeat update list on ng-change of filter input and reset index?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angular-material

I've replicated the scenario in this plnkr:

`<input type="text" ng-model="search.id" ng-change="ctrl.infiniteItems.fetchMoreItems_()">`

```
var vm = this;
  vm.infiniteItems = {
    numLoaded_: 0,
    toLoad_: 0,
    items: [],

    // Required.
    getItemAtIndex: function(index) {
      if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
        this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
        return null;
      }

      return this.items[index];
    },

    // Required.
    getLength: function() {
      return this.numLoaded_ + 3;
    },

    fetchMoreItems_: function(index) {
      if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
        this.toLoad_ += 10;
        var filtered = [];
        fetcher.fetch($scope.search.id).then(angular.bind(this, function(obj) {
          this.items = obj;
          this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;
          if (obj.length <= this.toLoad_) {
            this.items = this.items.concat(obj);
            this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;
          }
        }));
      }
    }
  }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/vnrEOmQJ96ZETQpzlaMj

I want to update the view when I enter a value, right now I can filter but i get the results only when I scroll which calls the method from the controller and displays results on the top and never stops scrolling, returns empty rows once the results are over.

I want it to stop when that happens, like it behaves without filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you want? - [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MXp2lX6MuTlHlWYrNsxH?p=preview)

Markup

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.id" ng-change="inputChange()">
```

JS

```
vm.infiniteItems = {
    numLoaded_: 0,
    toLoad_: 0,
    items: [],

    // Required.
    getItemAtIndex: function(index) {
      if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
        this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
        return null;
      }

      return this.items[index];
    },

    // Required.
    getLength: function() {
      return this.numLoaded_ + 3;
    },

    fetchMoreItems_: function(index) {
      if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
        this.toLoad_ += 10;
      }
    }
};

$scope.inputChange = function () {
    console.log($scope.search.id);
     fetcher.fetch($scope.search.id).then(angular.bind(this, function(obj) {
         console.log(obj);
         vm.infiniteItems = obj;
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply camden, only problem is it won't stop scrolling after the result set is over, any ideas?

Comment: @SinSync Hi. Sorry, I don't understand. Could you explain what this means - "it won't stop scrolling after the result set is over"?

Comment: the list keeps repeating empty rows after the filtered results are over, ive modified my original example : https://plnkr.co/edit/vnrEOmQJ96ZETQpzlaMj?p=preview if you input in the box and start scrolling till the end, you'll get a better idea. : )

Comment: @SinSync That seems to be the same Plunker as in the question.

Comment: Yeah but it isolates that part of the problem. For some reason your code doesn't work in the plnkr for me but works fine in the app, so just to save time I used the original one. : )

Comment: @SinSync I'm not sure how to help you much further. Nothing happens when I type in the input so I can't see the scrolling problem.

Comment: if you enter 'pack0' and then scroll you'll see the update and the thing I'm trying to explain. thanks a lot for taking the time though!

Comment: @SinSync I still don't see anything. :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122523/discussion-between-sinsync-and-camden-kid).